# gitlab-runner can not find docker image after build

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

The scene is very basic. There is a dockerfile on gitlab server and this repository is build by gitlab-runner using docker. There is a my pipeline:

```yaml
image: docker:latest

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

services:
  - name: docker:dind
    alias: docker

stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t swim-web-img .
  tags:
    - docker
    - dotnet

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker run -dp 8080:80 --name swim-web-cntr swim-web-img
  tags:
    - docker
    - dotnet
```

This is a create docker image but gitlab-runner can not find during build and test job:

```bash
Running with gitlab-runner 15.10.1 (dcfb4b66)
  on kmaster mA_Dauog, system ID: r_oo2GNSfyvuPo
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:32
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-madauog-project-2-concurrent-0 via kmaster...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
01:14
Using docker image sha256:1be445cc553ebefc75d9f4917065d9e94c21bc731bdffab90cde482469d9e4a7 for docker:latest with digest docker@sha256:c20b7d2415de59f308553646712d9b1d92f4186aeaf8b04afae7f42129dab425 ...
$ docker build -t swim-web-img .
#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 736B done
...
#18 naming to docker.io/library/swim-web-img done
#18 DONE 0.2s
WARNING: buildx: git was not found in the system. Current commit information was not captured by the build
Job succeeded
```

Test job return **Unable to find image 'swim-web-img:latest' locally** failed message and after try to login docker hub.

```bash
Running with gitlab-runner 15.10.1 (dcfb4b66)
  on kmaster mA_Dauog, system ID: r_oo2GNSfyvuPo
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:29
Preparing environment
00:01
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:03
Using docker image sha256:1be445cc553ebefc75d9f4917065d9e94c21bc731bdffab90cde482469d9e4a7 for docker:latest with digest docker@sha256:c20b7d2415de59f308553646712d9b1d92f4186aeaf8b04afae7f42129dab425 ...
$ docker run -dp 8080:80 --name swim-web-cntr swim-web-img
Unable to find image 'swim-web-img:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for swim-web-img, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 125
```

Additionaly I can not appear this image `docker image ls` output:

```bash
REPOSITORY                                                          TAG               IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
docker                                                              dind              1be445cc553e   12 hours ago   318MB
docker                                                              latest            1be445cc553e   12 hours ago   318MB
registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-helper   x86_64-dcfb4b66   217a980e5a21   3 days ago     64.6MB
ruby                                                                2.7               82ca169bb3c4   6 days ago     865MB
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk                                        7.0               fa397c19e0b5   6 days ago     775MB
docker                                                              <none>            e072c2e5e550   13 days ago    318MB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each job has its own independent docker daemon (as declared in your `services:`). Therefore, you cannot build and run the same image across jobs. When the job completes, the `docker:dind` service (the job's docker daemon) shuts down and any images pulled or built in the job are also removed.

You should either build and run the container in the same job or push the container image to a registry first and then pull it in the subsequent job.

Comment: Your advices work when only making test. For deploy application, this image should not destroyed. Also I want to see all image and containers on host when executing `docker ps` command. Can I run pipeline without docker dind service.

Comment: If you want to use the host docker daemon, you need to connect to the host daemon, not the `docker:dind` service. You can do this by mounting `/var/run/docker.sock` into your jobs or by making the host daemon network-available to the runner. @swim -- but generally, runners should be separate from your deployment targets.

Comment: This answer acceptable. I want to ask a lot of questions, but all of them are not related to this topic directly. I mean say, how is your application development cycle? Which did you tools linked gitlab at deployment stage? You said that "runners should be separate from your deployment targets". If I understood correctly, you use gitlab runners only development and test stage, then how did you deployment without runners? Actually, I am a little confused. I will another question about that but for the present, I mark green tick.

Comment: @swim what I mean by "runners should be separate from your deployment targets" is that your runner should be installed on a different host than your application servers. I mention this because your job seems to assume that that commands are running on the target host. While this is _possible_ to do, it's a bit unusual; you generally wouldn't want to have to install a runner on every application server you wish to deploy to. Instead, your runner should be able to perform a deployment without being hosted on the same server as the application server. One example would be to run commands over ssh

Comment: Thanks @sytech. On your recommendation, After remove **docker:dind** service and docker image statements at pipeline,  I made only ssh configuration between gitlab-runner and the remote host. Now all the pieces of the puzzle are in place :) It turns out that all the operations and configurations were very simple.